# How to print accuracy & loss of GAN to tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorboard, generative-adversarial-network

I've played around with GAN architecture, currently running a DC-GAN on MNIST dataset and I'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate the algorithm's accuracy & print it, along with the losses on tensorboard. Besides the generator & discriminator code which is straightforward, I've put the main code bellow:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from model import Discriminator, Generator, initialize_weights

# Hyperparameters etc.
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-4  # could also use two lrs, one for gen and one for disc
BATCH_SIZE = 128
IMAGE_SIZE = 64
CHANNELS_IMG = 1
NOISE_DIM = 100
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
FEATURES_DISC = 64
FEATURES_GEN = 64

transforms = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(
            [0.5 for _ in range(CHANNELS_IMG)], [0.5 for _ in range(CHANNELS_IMG)]
        ),
    ]
)

# If you train on MNIST, remember to set channels_img to 1
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root="dataset/", train=True, transform=transforms, download=True)

# comment mnist above and uncomment below if train on CelebA
#dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="celeb_dataset", transform=transforms)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
gen = Generator(NOISE_DIM, CHANNELS_IMG, FEATURES_GEN).to(device)
disc = Discriminator(CHANNELS_IMG, FEATURES_DISC).to(device)
initialize_weights(gen)
initialize_weights(disc)

opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
opt_disc = optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

fixed_noise = torch.randn(32, NOISE_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
writer_real = SummaryWriter(f"test_logs/real")
writer_fake = SummaryWriter(f"test_logs/fake")
writer = SummaryWriter(f"test_logs/scalar")

step = 0

gen.train()
disc.train()

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    # Target labels not needed! <3 unsupervised
    for batch_idx, (real, _) in enumerate(dataloader):
        real = real.to(device)
        noise = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
        fake = gen(noise)

        ### Train Discriminator: max log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        disc_real = disc(real).reshape(-1)
        loss_disc_real = criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
        disc_fake = disc(fake.detach()).reshape(-1)
        loss_disc_fake = criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))
        loss_disc = (loss_disc_real + loss_disc_fake) / 2
        disc.zero_grad()
        loss_disc.backward()
        opt_disc.step()

        ### Train Generator: min log(1 - D(G(z))) <-> max log(D(G(z))
        output = disc(fake).reshape(-1)
        loss_gen = criterion(output, torch.ones_like(output))
        gen.zero_grad()
        loss_gen.backward()
        opt_gen.step()

        writer.add_scalar('Loss G', loss_gen, global_step=step)
        writer.add_scalar('Loss D', loss_disc, global_step=step)

        # Print losses occasionally and print to tensorboard
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print(
                f"Epoch [{epoch}/{NUM_EPOCHS}] Batch {batch_idx}/{len(dataloader)} \
                  Loss D: {loss_disc:.4f}, loss G: {loss_gen:.4f}"
            )

            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = gen(fixed_noise)
                # take out (up to) 32 examples
                img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(real[:32], normalize=True)
                img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake[:32], normalize=True)

                writer_real.add_image("Real", img_grid_real, global_step=step)
                writer_fake.add_image("Fake", img_grid_fake, global_step=step)

            step += 1
```